# QGIS Expression builder cannot filter

Tags: qgis, expression

[image]

```
"name" like 'column%'
```

> Output preview: 0

or

```
"name" = 'column_title'
```

> Output preview: 0

No filtering results in expression. Tried Qgis 2.12 and 2.18 both on OS X. Data is from Open Street Map - geofabrik supplier.

Comment: Did you also click "select"? The preview at the bottom shows the result for a random line in the dataset and not the amount of filtered features.

Comment: In your picture you have as recent selection like 'Trunk%' and your value in the table is 'trunk'. Keep in mind that SQL is case sensitive. Use Qgis ILIKE-Operator or lower("highway") to avoid it. And also what you mean by "name" = 'column_title' and like 'column%' ? It sounds like you want to filter for a column-names, but you can only filter for row-values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output preview is just telling you the result of your expression applied to the first record. A `0` just means it is false for that record.

If you go ahead and press `select` you will actually apply the filter to all of your records.